# DataAnnotations with html submit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, data-annotations

If I want to submit a form using jQuery Ajax from the client, can I do any DataAnnotations inside that HTML submit form as opposed to a Html.BeginForm or Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: Do you mean, whether it will validate your model in the server if you pass it through jQuery?

Comment: Actually, I know now that the server validation (for what DataAnnotations are for) will work regardless (as long as you decorate the class's properties with the pertinent annotations). The client validation will need to be done via the jQuery validation since I wouldn't be using the HTML helper BeginForm.